# Where can I find the *.PLT file format specification

Tags: graphics, 3d

*.PLT files are used to plot drawings on plotter machines. Where can I find a file format specification to generate these files programmatically?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.plt mostly used by AutoCad. MOST of the time .plt files will contain HPGL commands because most AutoCad users have HP plotters or HP-compatible plotters.

The PLT file can have any type of print file inside it (HPGL/HPRTL/HPGL2/ECM/PostScript/etc.), it is a 'wrapper' around another file. The '.plt' extension keeps things simple for AutoCad users.

AutoCad expects the user to select a plotter, then creates the printable file using the plotter's driver and adds the .plt extension.

https://www.cadzation.com/help/pltfiles.htm

So, you should search specification for HPGL/HPRTL/HPGL2/ECM/PostScript/etc.

Comment: See this Wikipedia page for HPGL and HPGL2 file format specs: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP-GL